# C# - Use of wildcards inside csproj file and new files addition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

Inside **.csproj** files Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio as default keep a reference to every file used inside the project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Utils\Foo1Utils.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utils\Foo2Utils.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\FooService.cs" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

To avoid conflicts on csproj files inside our solution at every file addition, we started to use **wildcards**:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Utils\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\*.cs" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem is that apparently both on Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio is not possible to "explain" to the IDE that we are using wildcards, and when we add a new file to the project they add a new reference to the file ignoring the wildcard `*.cs` on the folder. It's still a good solution because we don't need to commit our .csproj at every file addition, but now we have to reset them each time... anyone knows if there is a solution?

EDIT: with **Rider** (JetBrains) there isn't this problem, if in the csproj there is a wildcard and I add a new file everything works fine.

Comment: Do you have subfolders within the Utils or Services folders that are having new files added?

Comment: @Poosh sometimes I have subfolders but in my experience it doesn't make a difference. I rarely alter my folders structure so usually I simply write "Utils\\*.cls" and "Utils\Subutils\\*.cs", just to have a bit of control.

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you try adding a new class to one of the folders that is referenced in the csproj file with a wildcard, then exit Visual Studio, are you prompted to save changes to the solution/project?

Comment: I usually use Xamarin Studio and one colleague of mine uses Visual Studio, and both of us have the same problem: if we add a file in a folder already "covered" with wildcard, ide adds the file in the csproj and we have to discard the modification.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the new format for projects ([.net core 2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/)) it will use wildcard includes without you having to specify it for files in the project folder. You can manually set the target framework in order to still compile to whatever target you want.

Comment: Thanks, I converted some of my old projects and yes, indeed with new format there is no need to include anything. By the way I had some problems in converting a couple of projects, and considering that with Rider wildcards work well I guess that the solution to my question is simply: it's a bug of Visual Studio, both on Mac and Win.

Comment: The csproj format is somewhat tricky to implement since it's quite old. Better to go forward in order to avoid old weirdness. Some of it might be fixed by pull requests in a few years.